# How do I create this Select Statement?

Tags: mysql, sql

There are two tables: employee and department.
Employee table has columns: empid, deptid, employeename
Departmen table has: deptid, deptname

I want to create a select statment which will list all employees who are part of department having more than 3 employees.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select empid, employeename
from Employee
where deptid in (
    select deptid
    from Employee
    group by deptid
    having count(*) > 3
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another approach...

```
Select e.empid, e.employeename
from employee e
where 3 <= (select count(e2.empid) 
            from employee e2 
            where e2.empid <> e.empid and e2.deptid = e.deptid)
```

Comment: :) talk about complicating things!

Comment: @Roopesh - agree it is complicated and expensive as well.. and also not recommended compared to first solution by @Jason. But its just another approach to achieve it. It will help the person to understand query more logically if he is a beginner. It reads - select employees where there exists more than 3 other employees in same department :) I like finding alternatives.